# ¿Cómo enviar un mensaje a la vista login, a la que te lleva la confirmación de correo de Laravel Auth si no estás logeado?

Tags: laravel

Necesito mostrar un mensaje después que la persona hace clic en el botón de confirmar email (el que le llega al correo del usuario y lo envía a la vista de login), porque a veces no tiene la sesión abierta y necesito indicarle para que debe hacerlo.

He intentado agregrar `->with('info', 'Mi mensaje');` en unas funciones de `VerifiesEmail.php` pero no lo he logrado.